# Promise.then(()=>function()) vs. Promise.then(function)

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm learning about Promise in Javascript and I can't figure out why these are the same:

```
let fifteen = Promise.resolve(15);
fifteen.then(value => console.log(value));
```

vs.

```
let fifteen = Promise.resolve(15);
fifteen.then(console.log);
```

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: If the function you want to call doesn't use `this`, or is bound, they are the same. However, when passed directly, unbound functions lose their `this` context when called. For `console.log`, it should work the same both ways.

Comment: This is unrelated to promises. It has to do with passing a callback. The principle is the same with, for example, `array.forEach`, or with `setTimeout` or your own function that can receive a callback.

Comment: @trincot Thanks, I need to get back to basic on callback here, why are the following have the same output?  

function test(callback) {
    callback("test-output");
}
  
test(console.log);
  
  vs. 
  
test((value) => console.log(value));

Comment: I added an answer where I address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is unrelated to promises. It has to do with passing a callback. The principle is the same with, for example, `array.forEach`, or with `setTimeout` or your own function that can receive a callback.

So for example, if you define such a function yourself, it could be (like you mentioned in comments):

```
function test(callback) { 
   callback("test-output"); 
}
```

If you want to *print* "test-output", you would call `test` like in this short version:

```
test(console.log);
```

You could also call it like in this longer version:

```
test((value) => console.log(value));
```

### The long version

In the latter case you actually create an anonymous (arrow) function on-the-fly:

```
(value) => console.log(value)
```

This is a wrapper around `console.log`. If you call it with some argument, you end up calling `console.log` with that same argument. You have in some way created a synonym for `console.log` because to the outside world it behaves in the same way. You could do something more elaborate, and define that function in a non-anonymous way:

```
function wrapper(value) { 
    console.log(value)
}
```

And then use that -- now *named* -- function at the place where we had the anonymous function:

```
test(wrapper);
```

We didn't change much: we just moved the function to another spot, turned it into a non-arrow function (not really needed), and gave it a name (`wrapper`). So the name `wrapper` is now synonym for that function. And so passing *that* to `test` is just the same thing as passing the literal function definition itself.

This makes very clear now that we just added a tiny, extra layer on top of the final call to `console.log`: first we call `test`, then `test` will call `wrapper`, and finally `wrapper` will call `console.log`.

### The short version

The first, shorter way of calling `test`, is not beating around the bush: it just says: "the function I want you to call is `console.log`". And so `test` calls it:

```
callback("test-output");
```

It provides the argument "test-output". Do realise that the `callback` variable is a reference to `console.log` now, since that is the argument we passed to `test`. Both `console.log` and `callback` now reference the *same* function. So `callback("test-output")` is just the same as `console.log("test-output")`.

So here we have one level less than in the longer version. The sequence is that we call `test`, and then `test` calls `console.log`. The wrapper thingie is not there.

NB: There are some things to say about `this` binding here, which does not have any bearing on the example above, but if that topic concerns/interests you, then read more about it in: [How does the `this` keyword work in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation make sense, I now understand the first case: "callback("test-output") is just the same as console.log("test-output")"

However, for the second case, I'm still a little confuse on the concept of wrapper around another function as in (value) => console.log(value). Is there another example/resource that you can point me to specific to this wrapper concept?

Comment: I extended my answer a bit, I hope it clarifies the wrapper concept.

Answer (score 0):

The difference of

`.then(console.log)`

`.then((value)=>console.log(value))` 
is just in the first case, `console.log` **implicitly** receive the result, but in the second case **explicitly** receive the result. So the result is same.

Comment: Thanks, So given a function, we will need to read the source code to find out if a function would implicitly receive the result? I'm still unclear, if you can provide an example code showing under what condition a function can receive an implicit return, that would be great.

Comment: @hubpixel I think this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1221966/JavaScript-Functions-Implicit-Parameters) can be helpful (about arguments obejct)

Comment: Thanks for the article. So in the case of .then(console.log) , where is the argument passed to the console.log?  I understand about the explicit part, but still confuse about the implicit.